# Spark 2.4 Got an error when resolving hostNames Falling back to /default-rack

Tags: apache-spark, hostname

Running an application in in client mode, the driver logs are printed with the below info messages, any idea on how to resolve this? Any spark configs to be updated? or missing?

```
[INFO ][dispatcher-event-loop-29][SparkRackResolver:54] Got an error when resolving hostNames. Falling back to /default-rack for all
```

The jobs runs fine, this msg is not in the executor logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28005

If you want to suppress this in the logs you can try to add this into your log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.SparkRackResolver=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen while using spart-submit with master `yarn` in a deploy mode **local** (not using `--deploy-mode cluster`) and the path to `topology.py` script is not correct into your `core-site.xml`.

Path to `core-site.xml` can be set via environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` (or `YARN_CONF_DIR`).

Check the path in the param `net.topology.script.file.name` value of `core-site.xml`.

If the path is incorrect, deploying driver in local mode will lead to error of executing with the following warning:

```
23/01/15 18:39:43 WARN ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running /home/alexander/xxx/.conf/topology.py 10.15.21.199
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py" (in directory "/home/john"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
...
23/01/15 18:39:43 INFO SparkRackResolver: Got an error when resolving hostNames. Falling back to /default-rack for all
```